# ¿Cómo tomar el valor de mis consultas SQL en el JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="conexion.jsp" %><!--incluimos conexion -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ScriptControlE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>cotizacion</title> 
    <%  
        String idlu =request.getParameter("lugar");
        String fe=request.getParameter("fecha");
        String nop=request.getParameter("nopersonas");
        int nump=Integer.parseInt(nop);
        String idpa =request.getParameter("grupopaquete");
        String idcu =request.getParameter("grupocubierto");
        String idado =request.getParameter("grupoadorno");

        double cl,cp,ca,cc;

            %>                               
            <style>
                td{
                    width: 100;
                }

               hr.v{
width: 1px;
height: 15px;
}
            </style>

             <script>
                  var xhr;
          function Ajax(){
               if(window.ActiveXObject){
                   xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
                 }else if ((window.XMLHttpRequest) || (typeof XMLHttpRequest)!=undefined){
                   xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else{
                 return;
                }
              return xhr;
          }
            function evento(head){
                divresul=document.getElementById('muestra');
                ajax=Ajax();
                ajax.open("GET",head);
                ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if(ajax.readyState===4){
                    divresul.innerHTML=ajax.responseText
                    }
                }
                ajax.send(null)
            }


            </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <form name="formularioc" method="post" action="cotizarBase.jsp">
            <h4><center>Detalles de la Cotizacion</center></h4>
            <center> 
                <div>
                <table style="border: darkorange">
             <tr>
                        <td>Nombre</td>
                        <td>Entrada</td>
                        <td>Crema</td>
                        <td>Plato Fuerte</td>
                        <td>Pastel</td>
                        <td>Cafe</td>
                        <td>Costo</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <%               
                        ResultSet res1;
                        String paq = "select * from paquete where idpaquete="+idpa+";";
                        res1 = sql.executeQuery(paq);
                        while (res1.next()) {
                    %>

                    <td> <% out.print(res1.getString(2));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res1.getString(3));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res1.getString(4));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res1.getString(5));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res1.getString(6));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res1.getString(7));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res1.getDouble(8));%> </td>

                    <%
                    cp=Double.valueOf(res1.getDouble(8));
                    }   
                    %>

            </tr> 
                </table>
                </div>
            </center>
            <hr class="v" />
            <center>
                <div>
                    <table>
            <tr>
<td>Lugar</td> <td>Descripcion</td> <td>Costo</td> <td>Fecha</td> <td>No. personas</td> <td>Cubierto</td>
<td>Descripcion</td> <td>Costo</td> <td>Adorno</td> <td>Descripcion</td> <td>Costo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <%               
                    ResultSet res;
                    String lugar = "select * from lugar where id_lugar="+idlu+";";
                    res = sql.executeQuery(lugar);
                    while (res.next()) {
                    %>
                    <td> <% out.print(res.getString(2));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res.getString(3));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res.getDouble(4));%> </td>
                    <%
                    cl=Double.valueOf(res.getDouble(4));
                    }
                    %>

                    <td><% out.print(fe);%></td>
                    <td><% out.print(nop);%></td>

                    <%               
                    ResultSet res2;
                    String cubier = "select * from cubierto where id_cubierto="+idcu+";";
                    res2 = sql.executeQuery(cubier);
                    while (res2.next()) {
                    %>
                    <td> <% out.print(res2.getString(2));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res2.getString(3));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res2.getDouble(4));%> </td>
                    <%
                    cc=Double.valueOf(res2.getDouble(4));
                    }
                    %>

                    <%               
                    ResultSet res3;
                    String ador = "select * from adorno where idadorno="+idado+";";
                    res3 = sql.executeQuery(ador);
                    while (res3.next()) {
                    %>
                    <td> <% out.print(res3.getString(2));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res3.getString(3));%> </td>
                    <td> <% out.print(res3.getDouble(4));%> </td>
                    <%                   
                    ca=Double.valueOf(res3.getDouble(4));
                    }
                    %>
                </tr>              
            </table>
                </div>
                </center>
            <div>

            <%

        double cotizacion=((cc*nump)+(ca*nump)+cl+(cp*nump));

            %>
        <center>
                <!--<a href="#" onclick="evento('advcdvzdv');">cotizar</a> -->


        </center>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Deberías darle formato a tu código usando el botón `{ }` y aclarar qué problema enfrentas. Mira esta guía _[ask]_.

Answer (score 0):

Mira un ejemplo no sé si te sirve, yo tengo una clase Conection en la cual hice un metodo que se llama getConection el cual me trae la conexion a la base de datos, invoco al prepareStatement y ya le paso la consulta, aunque yo todas las consultas las tengo en otra clase y mientras que haya algún registro me lo muestre

```
<%
                        Conection con = new Conection();
                        MemberSQL consultas = new MemberSQL();
                        try {
                            PreparedStatement stm = con.getConection().prepareStatement(consultas.getMember());
                            ResultSet result = stm.executeQuery();
                                %>
                                <table class="table table-striped" width="100%" align="center" id="tblList">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Nombre Completo</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Documento</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Tipo Documento</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Celular o Fijo</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Correo</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Perfil</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Estado</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Fecha Cumpleaños</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Dirección Casa</th>
                                <th class="color-tabla">Versículo</th>

                            </tr>
                                <%
                            while (result.next()) {

                                %>
                                 <tr>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(1)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(2)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(3)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(4)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(5)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(6)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(7)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(8)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(9)%></td>
                                <td class="color-tabla"><%=result.getString(10)%></td>

                                </tr>
                                <%

                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            out.print(e);
                        }
                    %>




                        </table>
                    </div>
```